# Access count of active users in month - Crosstab?

Tags: date, ms-access, crosstab

I have a query to find all active users within a given month, where a user has a start date and may or may not have an end date yet. Using parameters where I type in the end dates of the month I'm able to easily look at any single month.

(((TABLE.STARTDATE)<=[Last Day of month :]) AND ((TABLE.ENDDATE) Is Null)) OR (((TABLE.STARTDATE)<=[Last Day of month :]) AND ((TABLE.ENDDATE)>[Last Day of month :]));

I would now like a query to show all active users in each month across the year, so :

(((TABLE.STARTDATE)<=31/01/2021) AND ((TABLE.ENDDATE) Is Null)) OR (((TABLE.STARTDATE)<=31/01/2021) AND ((TABLE.ENDDATE)>31/01/2021));

would show me all users who were active on the last day of January 2021. Joe Bloggs for example might appear in the January count and the February count but have an end date in March and wouldn't be active in the March count.

I'm hoping for something that looks like this but which could update, so that I could count April and May without writing another query each month.

| JAN | FEB | MAR |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | 102 | 99 |

I'm picturing something like this as a starting point: Was Joe Bloggs active in this month (Y/N) and then  counts from there ... but accept that might be a stupid idea!

| JAN | FEB | MAR | APR |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Y | Y | N | N |

Thanks in advance, I just can't get my head around it!

Comment: Please have in mind, that SO is not a code writing forum but a code helping forum.

Comment: Edit question to show sample raw data. Making a CROSSTAB query stable to handle dynamic data range is tricky but possible. Review https://www.fmsinc.com/MicrosoftAccess/query/crosstab-report/index.html